# How to validate text box in gherkin language?

Tags: cucumber, bdd, gherkin

I need to validate "text box" which does not allow special character,Number more than 10000, and letters,

So my question is how to write in gerkin language ?

Answer (score 0):

`Gherkin` is not a programming language to have validations. You cannot inject variables into it. However, you can perform the validation in the step definition file and tag it to gherkin.

```
Scenario: I verify if the characters more than 100

Given I see the text box

And I verify, the text box does not contain characters more than ""
```

**The step definition file**

```
arg !< characters.length
```

`arg` is the argument you pass inside the double quotes in gherkin.

Answer (score 0):

Your task is to

- Find the value in the text box

  - The way to do this varies from environment to environment, Selenium may be a good way to interact with your system if it is a web application
- Save it in some variable
- Validate it against some known value in a step

I have written a few blog posts on how to use [Cucumber](https://cucumber.io/). This [blog post](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2015/01/30/bdd-with-cucumberjvm-at-geecon-tdd-2015) from 2015 may be a reasonable start. The cucumber version is a bit outdated. The process of implementing steps is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

Executable specifications (whether they are in Gherkin format or not) are meant to describe the behavior of the business people. I am pretty confident that not a single business person would talk about the how a single text box should behave.

My advice is to see what the actual business value is about and write the scenario from that perspective. Then the actual testing on this particular text box might not be described in the scenario, but it can be part of the underlying steps implementation.

In other words should the text box suddenly allow for numbers up to a million than the business value probably doesn't change. Therefore the scenario should not change, but the test code behind it might.